# Apache Reverse Proxy IIS Streaming File

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, reverse-proxy

We recently setup an apache reverse proxy with IIS sitting behind it. All of our apps work fine except for one.

In one app we will prepare and stream a PDF file to the user with the follow example code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + downloadName + "; size=" + downloadBytes.Length);
Response.OutputStream.Write(downloadBytes, 0, downloadBytes.Length);
Response.End();
```

The app will seem to hang and never stream the PDF. The app works fine with no proxy. And also if I take a pdf of the same size and store it on the server's file systems and then download from that directory it works fine. It seems to only have a problem when we try to stream using Response.

I suspected the connection wasn't being kept alive while the PDF generated (it takes about 5 to 7 seconds) but I have adjust the timeout and had no luck.

Here is my apache proxy config.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

<Proxy *>
```

Order deny,allow
Allow from all

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile C:/certs/example.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile c:/certs/example.key
ServerName www.example.com

ProxyVia On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/ timeout=360
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPreserveHost On
LogLevel debug
```

Answer (score 2):

So I solved my problem.

There was an internal process in the application that would use self referencing URLs to generate the PDF.

I had proxypreservehost on which was causing the PDF process to timeout because of some bad URLs it was generating.

I disabled proxypreservehost and it works like a charm!

Comment: +1 for coming back and answering your own question. Good etiquette!

Answer (score 0):

What about excluding the pdf file using the following '!' directive from [mod_proxy manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)?

> The ! directive is useful in
>   situations where you don't want to
>   reverse-proxy a subdirectory, e.g.
>
> ProxyPass /mirror/foo/i ! ProxyPass
>   /mirror/foo http://backend.example.com
>
> will proxy all requests to /mirror/foo
>   to backend.example.com except requests
>   made to /mirror/foo/i.